# Get TaskID for Case Activities

Tags: acumatica

I was getting TaskID for Case Activities  (Screen ID - SP203010) using Acumatica Web API. Now after upgrading it to version 6.0, I am not getting that. I have also tried different properties available but seems nothing is getting me that TaskID.

I am storing these activities into my database pulling from Acumatica Partner Portal and to avoid duplicate activities being imported, I was comparing it with TaskID.

Below is the code snippet I am using to get TaskID

```html
SP203010WS.Screen context = new SP203010WS.Screen();
context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
context.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
context.EnableDecompression = true;
context.Timeout = 1000000;
context.Url = "https://sso.acumatica.com/Soap/SP203010.asmx";

PartnerPortalCreds loginCreds = GetCreds();
string username = loginCreds.PARTPRTUSE;
string password = loginCreds.PARTPRTPAS;

SP203010WS.LoginResult result = context.Login(username, password);

SP203010WS.Content content = context.GetSchema();
context.Clear();
string[][] export = context.Export
(
 new SP203010WS.Command[]
{
 new SP203010WS.Value
 {
  Value = currentAcumaticaCaseNo,
  LinkedCommand = content.Case.CaseID
 },

 content.Activities.Type,
 content.Activities.Summary,
 new SP203010WS.Field { FieldName="Body", ObjectName="Activities"},
 content.Activities.StartDate,
 content.Activities.CreatedBy,
 new SP203010WS.Field { FieldName="TaskID", ObjectName="Activities"},
},
 null,
 0, true, true
);
```

Let me know whether it has been moved or deprecated in newer version. What shall I be using instead of TaskID or where can I find that TaskID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Krunal, as Ken mentioned, after upgrade to 6.0 value pair TaskID and NoteID is only available in the Obsolete_EPActivity table. One should use Obsolete_EPActivity table to replace obsolete TaskID integer values with actual NoteID GUIDs.

There is no way to access Obsolete_EPActivity table through Web Services. After upgrade to 6.0, Acumatica inserts new Activities only in the CRActivity table.

To avoid duplicate activities, you have to store actual NoteID GUIDs in your database instead of obsolete TaskID integer values and compare GUIDs while importing records.

For previously imported activities you will also have to replace TaskID values with actual NoteID GUIDs. Searching for CRActivity record based on CaseID, Subject and CreatedDateTime field values stored in your DB, you should find appropriate record and use its NoteID to replace legacy TaskID value.

Answer (score 2):

In Acumatica 6.0 table EPActivity was splitted on CRActivity, SMEmail and PMTimeActivity. Original table was renamed to Obsolete_EPActivity.

Now NoteID is the key field on all tables. SMEmail and PMTimeActivity contains RefNoteID field - foreign key from CRActivity.

You may find value pair TaskID and NoteID in table - Obsolete_EPActivity

Comment: Understood, however I need to get TaskID also using same Screen ID SP203010 using Web API. Is there a way to get and access Obsolete_EPActivity object through Web API.